# How can I determine which laptop models are compatible which docking stations? (Lenovo X201)

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, compatibility, docking-station

I have a certain laptop model (a bit old by now) and I want to get a docking station for it. But - I have no idea whether docking stations from my manufacturer are generic or not; or how their model numbers correspond to laptop model numbers etc. I can't really figure this out looking at the manufacturer's website, and Googling has not helped (although maybe I was searching for the wrong thing).

While my question is more general, I'm specifically interested in a docking station for a Lenovo X201 laptop; either specific or general answers are appreciated.

Comment: Although you can generally find this information online, a good resource for what to buy is the sales department of the manufacturer.  They get paid to help you buy stuff and are always happy to advise you on what's compatible,

Comment: @fixer1234: They would only recommend items that are currently in production; I would mostly be interested in older models.

Comment: Companies want to keep existing customers happy.  Sure, it would be great if you buy a new product from them.  But it's also beneficial if you continue to be a satisfied user of their own products rather than switch to a competitor's products.  They'll get an answer from their tech support people for you (or tech support will help you directly), with info on old stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me about 30 seconds to type `lenovo x201 docking station` into DuckDuckGo, which returned as among the top hits the [Docking Station options for X200, X200s, X201, X201s, X201i, X201si](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Docking-Station-options-for-X200-X200s-X201-X201s-X201i-X201si/ta-p/400573) thread on Lenovo Forums. That tells us that there are two docking station options for your laptop, namely:

- X200 Ultrabase
- Lenovo USB Port Replicator with Digital Video

The Lenovo forum thread [Thinkpad x201 and x200 Ultrabase docking](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Thinkpad-x201-and-x200-Ultrabase-docking/td-p/1857323) specifically indicates that the X201 is physically compatible with the X200 Ultrabase docking station.

Passing the search on to Amazon, `lenovo x201 docking station` gives among the top suggestions:

- [Lenovo ThinkPad X200 UltraBase](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EVY5Y6), $37.17
- [LENOVO 44C0554 LENOVO THINKPAD X200 ULTRABASE Stations > Lenovo Thinkpad 44C0554 Docking station X200 X201 X200S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016YK906Y), $199 (new) or $99.99 (used)

*No affiliation with the sellers of any of the linked products; examples only.*